# Editing tags with "Edit tags" in a question redirects me to showing code

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, tags, edits

I edited tags with the "Edit tags" link (not in edit mode) for this question by adding the `forms` tag:

- [PHP - Blog post system not working properly / can't post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635695/php-blog-post-system-not-working-properly-cant-post)

and it redirected me to another page with just the following showing as code:

```
{"success":true,"html":"<a href=\"/questions/tagged/php\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;php&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">php</a><a href=\"/questions/tagged/html\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;html&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">html</a><a href=\"/questions/tagged/mysql\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;mysql&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">mysql</a><a href=\"/questions/tagged/forms\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;forms&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">forms</a>"}
```

Here is the revisions link:

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53635695/4

This is the 2nd time this happened to me this morning by adding the `sessions` tag. Another one earlier showed the following, but I didn't retain the question's URL.

```
{"success":true,"html":"<a href=\"/questions/tagged/php\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;php&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">php</a><a href=\"/questions/tagged/session\" class=\"post-tag\" title=\"show questions tagged &#39;session&#39;\" rel=\"tag\">session</a>"}
```

Is this a network problem or is it just me?

I'm using Opera as my browser if that is relevant.

Comment: It's not just you. FF 63.0.3 is doing the same

Comment: I can reproduce.  Win 10 pro, latest chrome

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I wonder if this was already asked?

Comment: I haven't had this happen to me... well, ever. I didn't see any Meta Qs about it so I think it just started

Comment: I was just about to post my own bug report when you posted this.  AFAIK, this is the first report.  inline edits were working earlier.

Comment: @Machavity Maybe you were in full edit mode? This happened to me with using the "Edit tags" button/link.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Sorry, I meant I've not seen this bug before today. It's happening to me in the quick tag edits

Comment: Obviously they can't [HandleSuccess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207388/why-is-the-handlesuccess-method-such-a-terrible-one)

Comment: @Machavity ah, ok.

Comment: I was just coming to report this issue as well. Seems browser independent since I also see it with Safari on macOS. It happens every time I use the Edit Tags link. Once I see the JSON response I go back to the question, reload, and the tags show the updates I made.

Comment: @rmaddy I think there's something wonky happening on the network these past few days. I noticed another thing that the response from loading a questions thread was rather slow, and also not showing any questions also, this being another probable bug but I didn't ask about it.

Comment: I, too, am seeing it: IE 11. In my case, I get a prompt whether to save or open a `json` file from stackoverflow.com. Using the full edit capability doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: Reproduced, identified cause, notified devs. Sorry for the inconvenience; please stand by.

Comment: MSE bug report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319505/tag-edits-result-in-a-success-screen-instead-of-the-updated-post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed now. Details on MSE: [Tag edits result in a "success" screen instead of the updated post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319505/tag-edits-result-in-a-success-screen-instead-of-the-updated-post/319513#319513)

Comment: I would have submitted my question earlier (this morning) when the first similar issue happened and thought it was just a local issue in my browser. When I noticed it happened again (and a few times again after), is when I decided to post the question. Sometimes it is a local issue and was the reason why I hesitated to post. Glad this is fixed, cheers.

Comment: Don't feel bad... I was cussin' at my keyboard all morning 'cause I kept hitting ctrl+enter and the edits wouldn't go through; thought I had a sticky ctrl key.

Comment: Heh; I'll bet that made it all that much more harder to figure out where the problem was in sorts. I was just a bit paranoid that my question wouldn't have been well-accepted and people might have thought that it was "just me" and they couldn't or didn't know how to reproduce it.