# stackoverflow.com is not working

Tags: bug, ssl

Any idea why is stackoverflow not working?

Normal mode:

[image: The browser says the site is not secure in the address bar. The page is completely blank except for the text "StackExchange WebSocket server v2".]

Incognito mode + certificate:

[image: Issued to qa.sockets.stackexchange.com and valid until July 26th 2019.]

Comment: Working for me.

Comment: Did you check your console for errors? Try it with plugins disabled or in incognito mode? Try another browser?

Comment: Works for me and it is a bit strange that says the page has no valid certificate. Does something alter your host resolution?

Comment: @Kendra, whole http response is pure text saying: StackExchange WebSocket server v2

Comment: [Possibly related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377497/7296893). I would assume this is a valid bug report. Please provide certificate info, this might also be a badly executed MITM (click on the _not secure_ alert, then _certificate_, and screenshot)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - I've updated my post

Comment: Thanks, we can be pretty sure this is a valid bug report, since that's an SE-owned signed certificate that's used for websockets, and not for the main site.

Comment: Could be a DNS issue at OP's side, it's happened before. I'll try finding the previous question(s).

Comment: Related: [Certificate error when using stackoverflow.com from certain IP addresses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358327/certificate-error-when-using-stackoverflow-com-from-certain-ip-addresses)

Comment: It's back on now.